# Curvature - Linear Assumption

Tags: plotting

[image]

They asked if the linear assumption is correct, but I just see a graph and based on the data I was taught that a curvature is nonlinear so nonlinear means that a graph is incorrect?

What is the assumption? I know this may seem stupid, but I still haven't grasped the question.

Comment: What is this question about? Is it related to regression? Because the top says residuals? Maybe it implies whether the "assumption of residuals for a linear fit is correct", which is not.

Comment: The same way you are unsure so was I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the linear assumption is incorrect since the graph is non linear

Comment: I believe we both will use that its nonlinear to determine the answer